# Does factory resetting a Kindle Fire remove parental controls, and if so, how to secure it?

Tags: factory-reset, amazon-kindle-fire, parental-control

If deregistering or a factory reset removes parental controls, what is to stop my teen from doing this to remove my oh so horrible restrictions?